# Run a number of groups of QProcess' after each other

Tags: qt, asynchronous, polling, qprocess

I need to call an external program `N` number of times. I'd like to do this in parallel. So my strategy thus far has been to start `N` QProcesses and keep a count of ones that have started and ones that have finished. (So I can figure out when they have all finished).

However, the external program takes up a fair bit of RAM, so I do not want more the 4 parallel processes at any one time.

What is a good strategy for this?

I don't think signals/slots is enough to achieve this (I can't think of a method that isn't highly convoluted)...perhaps I can do something with a queue?

How can I ensure I only have 4 processes running at any one time?
How can I then figure out when all `N` processes have finally finished?

(Answers for pyside/pyqt preferred, but C++ is Ok)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof-of-concept:

h file

```
#ifndef CPROCESSRUNNER_H
#define CPROCESSRUNNER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQueue>

class QProcess;

class CProcessRunner : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int processCount READ processCount WRITE setProcessCount)
public:
    explicit CProcessRunner(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~CProcessRunner();

    void addProcess(const QString& program);

    int processCount() const;

public slots:
    void setProcessCount(int arg);

private slots:
    void startFreeProcesses();

private:
    int getActiveProcessCount() const;

    QQueue<QProcess*> m_processes;
    int m_processCount;
};

#endif // CPROCESSRUNNER_H
```

cpp file

```
#include "CProcessRunner.h"
#include <QProcess>
CProcessRunner::CProcessRunner(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_processCount(0)
{

}

CProcessRunner::~CProcessRunner()
{

}

void CProcessRunner::addProcess(const QString& program)
{
    QProcess* pProcess = new QProcess(this);
    pProcess->setObjectName(program);
    m_processes.enqueue(pProcess);
    startFreeProcesses();
}

int CProcessRunner::processCount() const
{
    return m_processCount;
}

void CProcessRunner::setProcessCount(int arg)
{
    m_processCount = arg;
}

void CProcessRunner::startFreeProcesses()
{
    while (!m_processes.isEmpty() && (getActiveProcessCount() < m_processCount)) {
        QProcess* pProcess = m_processes.dequeue();
        connect(pProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(startFreeProcesses()));
        connect(pProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int)), pProcess, SLOT(deleteLater()));

        pProcess->start(pProcess->objectName());
        pProcess->waitForStarted(-1);
    }
}

int CProcessRunner::getActiveProcessCount() const
{
    int result = 0;
    foreach (QProcess* pProcess, findChildren<QProcess*>()) {
        if (pProcess->state() == QProcess::Running) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: this looks like a really good start. How would we know when all processes are finished?
I suppose in the calling function you could put something like `while (process_runner.getActiveProcessCount() > 0) continue`...would that be best?

Comment: You can check in startFreeProcesses is getActiveProcessCount equa tol zero. Each, after finished, you will chech is already all processes are finished.

Comment: `m_processCount` should get renamed to `m_maxAsyncProcessCount`, or something similar.  Other than that, looks great, and gets the job done!

Comment: Your answer does not work without modification. The loop in startFreeProcesses() could never run because m_processCount was never incremented. I added the line setProcessCount(processCount() + 1); in addProcess. Then in startFreeProcess, decremented processCount ( setProcessCount(processCount() -1); ). These two changes made it work for me. Other than that, great code!

Comment: @MaxTither this is a feature by design :) This is a limit of processes, that you can run, by default you cannot run processes. Just call setProcessCount method before addProcess.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here is my current implementation using Pyside.
I wanted to be able to capture the output of each process and pass it on (for display in e.g. a `QTextEdit` or similar). To this end, I assigned each process a number and connected it's stdout and stderr to slots which will then emit the message and the process position.
I'm not convinced by my current implementation of that functionality, but here goes:

```
class ProcessRunner(QtCore.QObject):  
'''
Runs N processes in groups of M
'''    

singleProcessFinished = QtCore.Signal()
error = QtCore.Signal(tuple) #(process number, message)
message = QtCore.Signal(tuple) #(process number, message)

def __init__(self, maxProcesses=4, parent=None):
  super(ProcessRunner, self).__init__(parent)
  self.processQueue = Queue.Queue()  
  self.maxProcesses = maxProcesses
  self.activeProcessCount = 0

  self._processNumber = 0

def addProcess(self, program, args):
  '''
  Add a process to the process queue

  Args:

    program (str): String of program path and arguments, separated by one or more spaces    
  '''
  self._processNumber += 1
  if self._processNumber == self.maxProcesses:
    self._processNumber = 0


  proc = QtCore.QProcess(self)
  proc.readyReadStandardError.connect(lambda pos=self._processNumber, process=proc: self.emit_error(pos, proc))
  proc.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(lambda pos=self._processNumber, process=proc: self.emit_output(pos, proc))
  self.processQueue.put((proc, program, args))
  self.startFreeProcesses()

def startFreeProcesses(self):
  '''
  Starts all waiting processes up to a maximum of self.maxProcesses
  '''
  while (not self.processQueue.empty()) and (self.activeProcessCount < self.maxProcesses):
    proc, program, args = self.processQueue.get()
    proc.finished.connect(self.startFreeProcesses)
    proc.finished.connect(proc.deleteLater)
    proc.finished.connect(self.singleProcessFinished.emit)
    proc.finished.connect(self._decreaseActiveProcessCount)

    proc.start(program, args)
    proc.waitForStarted(-1)
    self._increaseActiveProcessCount()

def _decreaseActiveProcessCount(self):
  self.activeProcessCount -= 1

def _increaseActiveProcessCount(self):
  self.activeProcessCount += 1

def emit_error(self, pos, proc):    
  self.error.emit(pos, str(proc.readAllStandardError()))

def emit_error(self, pos, proc):    
  self.error.emit(pos, str(proc.readAllStandardOutput()))
```

Comment: I think, that bad way calculate free processes by hand. This information can be obtained and calculated at run time, from all child processes. In your case very importent when you will get free processes count. If this will be between finished signal and _decreaseActiveProcessCount function you will get wrong count.